# Disable bootstrap multiselect deselect all button

Tags: html, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to disable the `Deselect All` button. I want to keep the `Select All` button too.

**Here's my select**:

```
<select id="typeCheckboxSelect" class="selectpicker" name="typeSelector[]" multiple="multiple">
   <option class='typeCheckbox' type='checkbox' value='test1'>Test One</option>
   <option class='typeCheckbox' type='checkbox' value='test2'>Test Two</option>
   <option class='typeCheckbox' type='checkbox' value='test3'>Test Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can achieve this using javascript or jQuery.
I have used jQuery for that. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [onSelectAll callback](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onSelectAll), you can hide or disable the button, depending on your selections.

You will also probably want to include logic to re-enable the button given certain situations, but I do not know when those situations would be for you. Note that this onSelectAll callback will occur if you manually select every entry.

**html:**

```
<div id="selectContainer">
   <select id="typeCheckboxSelect" multiple="multiple">
      <option value='test1'>Test One</option>
      <option value='test2'>Test Two</option>
      <option value='test3'>Test Three</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

**MultiSelect Initialization:**

```
$("#typeCheckboxSelect").multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    onSelectAll: function() {
        $("#selectContainer .multiselect-container input[value='multiselect-all']").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

This will simply disable the button. If you want to re-enable it, you would call the below code in whatever handler you want.

```
$("#selectContainer .multiselect-container input[value='multiselect-all']").prop('disabled', false);
```

I have created a [fiddle demonstrating it here](https://jsfiddle.net/1qjxf0em/3/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0ouub4kw/52/) fiddle

```js
$('#select_all').click(function() {
  $('#typeCheckboxSelect option').prop('selected', true);
  $("#de_select_all").prop('disabled', false);
});

$('#de_select_all').click(function() {
  $('#typeCheckboxSelect option').prop('selected', false);
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});

$(document).on('change', '#typeCheckboxSelect', function() {
  $("#de_select_all").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="typeCheckboxSelect" class="selectpicker" name="typeSelector[]" multiple="multiple">
   <option class='typeCheckbox' type='checkbox' value='test1'>Test One</option>
   <option class='typeCheckbox' type='checkbox' value='test2'>Test Two</option>
   <option class='typeCheckbox' type='checkbox' value='test3'>Test Three</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" id="select_all" name="select_all" value="Select All">
<br>
<input type="button" id="de_select_all" name="de_select_all" value="De Select All">
```

Comment: Sorry for the real late answer. I'm using a bootstrap multiselect select which has a built in select all button. I found a way to hide that select all button but that hides it in every single select. Heres the way I hide it: $('.multiselect-item.multiselect-all').hide(); I like your answer but it would not fit my use. Thanks anyways!